# How to create BeginStoryboard in code behind for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML and I wish to convert this to code behind, I have been able to successfully create the animations so the control fades in & out as expected, but I'm having trouble converting the IsMouseOver trigger to code behind:

```
 <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.Loaded"
                          SourceName="NotificationGrid">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BeginNotificationStoryboard">
                    <Storyboard x:Name="NotificationStoryboard">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NotificationGrid"
                                         From="0.01"
                                         To="1"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.5" />

                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NotificationGrid"
                                         From="1"
                                         To="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                         BeginTime="0:0:5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <SeekStoryboard Offset="0:0:3"
                                    BeginStoryboardName="BeginNotificationStoryboard" />
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginNotificationStoryboard" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <SeekStoryboard Offset="0:0:3"
                                    BeginStoryboardName="BeginNotificationStoryboard" />
                    <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginNotificationStoryboard" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The issue I am have is how do I know what the 'BeginStoryboardName' value should be for the instances of the SeekStoryboard classes since I haven't had to create a BeginStoryboard instance to get the animation on loading to work as expected.

```
var loadingAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0.01, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
var closingAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
{
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};

Storyboard.SetTarget(loadingAnimation, AssociatedObject);
Storyboard.SetTarget(closingAnimation, AssociatedObject);

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(loadingAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(closingAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

Storyboard.SetTarget(loadingAnimation, AssociatedObject);
Storyboard.SetTarget(closingAnimation, AssociatedObject);

var storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(loadingAnimation);
storyboard.Children.Add(closingAnimation);

var enterSeekStoryboard = new SeekStoryboard
{
    Offset = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    // What value should go here?
    BeginStoryboardName = ""
};

var exitSeekStoryboard = new SeekStoryboard
{
    Offset = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    // What value should go here?
    BeginStoryboardName = ""
};

var trigger = new Trigger
{
    Property = UIElement.IsMouseOverProperty,
    Value = true
};

trigger.EnterActions.Add(enterSeekStoryboard);
trigger.ExitActions.Add(exitSeekStoryboard);

var style = new Style();
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);

AssociatedObject.Style = style;

storyboard.Completed += HandleOnCompleted;
storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: I guess that... You will have to create them after all? You got it to work coincidentally just because the animation is starting automatically by default, when the control is loaded. But that won't cut it for the MouseOver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your full code would be something like this. I've left some comments to point out some issues I've found:

```
var loadingAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0.01, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
var closingAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
{
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};

Storyboard.SetTarget(loadingAnimation, AssociatedObject);
Storyboard.SetTarget(closingAnimation, AssociatedObject);

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(loadingAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(closingAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

Storyboard.SetTarget(loadingAnimation, AssociatedObject);
Storyboard.SetTarget(closingAnimation, AssociatedObject);

var storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(loadingAnimation);
storyboard.Children.Add(closingAnimation);
// Subscription to events must be done at this point, because the Storyboard object becomes frozen later on
storyboard.Completed += HandleOnCompleted;

string storyBoardName = "BeginNotificationStoryboard";

// We define the BeginStoryBoard action for the EventTrigger
var beginStoryboard = new BeginStoryBoard();
beginStoryboard.Name = storyBoardName;
beginStoryboard.Storyboard = storyboard;

// We create the EventTrigger
var eventTrigger = new EventTrigger(Control.LoadedEvent);
eventTrigger.Actions.Add(beginStoryboard);

// Actions for the entering animation
var enterSeekStoryboard = new SeekStoryboard
{
    Offset = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    BeginStoryboardName = storyBoardName
};
var enterPauseStoryboard = new PauseStoryboard
{
    BeginStoryboardName = storyBoardName
};

// Actions for the exiting animation
var exitSeekStoryboard = new SeekStoryboard
{
    Offset = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    BeginStoryboardName = storyBoardName
};
var exitResumeStoryboard = new ResumeStoryboard
{
    BeginStoryboardName = storyBoardName
};

var trigger = new Trigger
{
    Property = UIElement.IsMouseOverProperty,
    Value = true
};

trigger.EnterActions.Add(enterSeekStoryboard);
trigger.EnterActions.Add(enterPauseStoryboard);
trigger.ExitActions.Add(exitSeekStoryboard);
trigger.ExitActions.Add(exitResumeStoryboard);

var style = new Style();
// The name of the Storyboard must be registered so the actions can find it
style.RegisterName(storyBoardName, beginStoryboard);
// Add both the EventTrigger and the regular Trigger
style.Triggers.Add(eventTrigger);
style.Triggers.Add(trigger);

AssociatedObject.Style = style;

// No need for storyboard.Begin()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created Storyboard but not BeginStoryboard. So do it like this:

```
var storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(loadingAnimation);
storyboard.Children.Add(closingAnimation);

var beginStoryboard = new BeginStoryboard(){ Name="BeginNotificationStoryboard", Storyboard = storyboard};

var enterSeekStoryboard = new SeekStoryboard
{
    Offset = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    // What value should go here?
    BeginStoryboardName = "BeginNotificationStoryboard"
};
```

Dont forget to add your beginStoryboard to EventTrigger like it was before.

Actually original XAML code used BeginNotificationStoryboard id just to remove some code duplicates.
If you don't want it anymore just add it to TriggerActions like this:

```
trigger.EnterActions.Add(beginStoryboard);
```

Than you don't need to specify the name.